# @Html.RadioButtonFor have same value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My form has a radio group for the civilities.

## View

```
<div class="form-radio-group">
    @foreach (var civility in Model.Civilities)
    {
        <label>                                    
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Data.CivilityId, civility.Id, new { id = $"CivilityID-{civility.Id}", @required = "required" })
            @civility.Name                                    
        </label>
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Data.CivilityId, "")
</div>
```

However, this isn't working for me. Here is my rendered html:

```
<div class="form-radio-group">
    <label>                                    
        <input id="CivilityID-1" name="Data.CivilityId" required="required" type="radio" value="3">
        Monsieur                                    
    </label>
    <label>                                    
        <input id="CivilityID-2" name="Data.CivilityId" required="required" type="radio" value="3">
        Madame                                     
    </label>
    <label>                                    
        <input id="CivilityID-3" name="Data.CivilityId" required="required" type="radio" value="3">
        Autre                                    
   </label>                         
</div>
```

As you can see, the value is the same for all inputs. 
The same it is for this:

```
<div class="form-radio-group">
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Data.DifferentBilling, true, new { id = $"DifferentBilling-true" }) 
        Yes
    </label>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Data.DifferentBilling, false, new { id = $"DifferentBilling-false" }) 
        No
    </label>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Data.DifferentBilling, "")
</div>
```

What can I do, to get different values in the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem wasn't by me but from the frontend. How I did it works totaly fine. I don't even have to do my own id `new { id = $"DifferentBilling-false" }` 
Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use different names for different radio button list.
So try to change the names instead.